# Writing RSpec tests using MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, rspec-rails

Here is my test in my controller:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all comments as @comments" do
    comment = Comment.create! valid_attributes
    get :index, { :url => "http://localhost:3000", :use_route => :good_comments}
    assigns(:comments).should eq([comment])
  end
end
```

When I run the test, it has different values for `:comments` and `comment`. The first is what one would expect:

```
#<MyComments::Comment _id: BSON::ObjectId('4f0f7c41516d9f5a4a000001'), comment: "Some comment", created_at: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 00:35:13 UTC +00:00, images: [], resource_hash: "aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwLw==", updated_at: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 00:35:13 UTC +00:00, urls: [], user_id: nil>
```

The second is just odd:

```
#<Plucky::Query sort: [["created_at", -1]], transformer: #<Proc:0x007fe86e3184c8@/Users/shamoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongo_mapper-0.10.1/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:79 (lambda)>
```

I'm not sure what's going on, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks =)

**EDIT: Adding Controller Code**

```
# POST /comments
# POST /comments.json
def create
  @comment = Comment.new params[:comment]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# GET /comments
# GET /comments.json
def index
  url = ""
  if params[:url]
    url = params[:url]
  end
  resource_hash = Comment.encode_url url

  @newComment = Comment.new
  @newComment.resource_hash = resource_hash

  @comments = Comment.find_all_by_resource_hash resource_hash
  @comments = Comment.sort(:created_at.desc)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @comments }
  end
end
```

**EDIT: UPDATED index ACTION**

```
def index
  url = ""
  if params[:url]
    url = params[:url]
  end
  resource_hash = Comment.encode_url url

  @newComment = Comment.new
  @newComment.resource_hash = resource_hash

  @comments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).sort(:created_at.desc)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @comments }
  end
end
```

Comment: Post the controller code as well please, for the `create` action, and any related before/after filters.

Comment: Oops I mean index action! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@comments = Comment.find_all_by_resource_hash resource_hash
@comments = Comment.sort(:created_at.desc)
```

Thats your problem, you are overwriting the @comments variable in the second line, try this for a start, I'm not sure if it is going to let you call sort on that but well see:

```
@comments = Comment.find_all_by_resource_hash resource_hash
@comments = @comments.sort(:created_at.desc)
```

UPDATE

Try doing this:

```
@comments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).sort(:created_at.desc).all
```

Comment: Updated the index action (see code above). Still fails the test

Comment: I think the problem is that RSpec isn't accessing my DB. How can I tell it my DB parameters?

Comment: Should be setup in your `test` environment probably.